# Bind/assignment operator works for function returning String but not for function returning Int

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

why does Prog A compile and run fine, whereas Prog B fails to compile? Thanks

**Prog A**

```
func :: String -> String
func a = a

mydofn a = do 
  x <- func a
  return x

main = print "Finished"
```

**Prog B**

```
func :: Int -> Int
func a = a

mydofn a = do 
  x <- func a
  return x

main = print "Finished"
```

**Prog B Compilation Error :**

```
Couldn't match expected type `m0 t0' with actual type `Int'
In the return type of a call of `func'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: x <- func a
In the expression:
  do { x <- func a;
       return x }
```

Comment: What else did you want `mydofn` to do? It would clarify your purpose, and maybe help us give more helpful answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With do-notation, this code:

```
mydofn a = do 
  x <- func a
  return x
```

is just syntax sugar for

```
mydofn a = func a >>= (\x -> return x)
```

Now, `>>=` has type `Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, but in your second example the application `func a` has type `Int`, which can't be unified with `Monad m => m a` (since `Int` is on its own and not inside some `m`), and this is what the type checker tells you ("Couldn't match `m a` with `Int`"). But why did this work in the first case?

Strings in Haskell are just lists of characters (`[Char]`). And there is [a `Monad` instance for `[a]` in the standard library](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Base.html#Monad) which looks like this:

```
instance  Monad []  where
    m >>= k             = foldr ((++) . k) [] m
    return x            = [x]
```

So `[Char]` gets unified with `Monad m => m a` (with `m = []` and `a = Char`) and your first example becomes

```
mydofn a = foldr ((++) . (\x -> [x])) [] (func a)
```

or equivalently

```
mydofn a = concat . map (\x -> [x]) $ func a
```

This just maps each character of the string to a singleton string (`"abc"` gets mapped to `["a", "b", "c"]`) and then concatenates all resulting strings together (`["a", "b", "c"]` becomes `"abc"`).

Answer (score 4):

In prog A, you're using the list monad, because `String = [Char]`.
There's no Int monad!
In prog A,

```
mydofn a = do 
  x <- func a
  return x
```

is equivalent to

```
mydofn a = [x | x <- func a]
```

so it actually just runs through the elements of the list, not changing anything.

In prog A, `m0 t0` matches `[] Char`, you can't write `Int` as `m0 t0` so that's why you got the error with prog B.

---

The `mydofn` is equivalent to

```
mydofn a = do 
  func a
```

which is equivalent to `mydofn a = func a` which means the same as `mydofn a = a`.

I take it this was a cut down example for the purposes of clarifying the question. What else did you want to do with `mydofn`?

Maybe you meant

```
mydofn a = do 
  x <- return (func a)
  return x
```

which would let it work with an Int, but I'm still not sure what your purpose is.